# How to send mail using Openpop.net?

Tags: c#, openpop

I using [OpenPop.net](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/) to get mail from server, but i can't find method send mail in [OpenPop.net](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/), how to send mail in [OpenPop.net](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: POP3 is only for retrieval. Use SMTP for sending.

Comment: Did my answer help you to get what you are looking for? If yes, feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 4):

POP3 is an email retrieval protocol. It is not used for sending. To send email, you need to use an SMTP client.

There is one in the .NET BCL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I have been working on `OpenPop.Net` for quite a while. Here is a simple code for sending email using gmail account.

```
protected void btnSendMail_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SmtpClient c = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        MailAddress add = new MailAddress(txtReceiverEmailAddr.Text);
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.To.Add(add);
        msg.From = new MailAddress(txtYourEmailAddr.Text);
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
        msg.Body = txtBody.Text;
        c.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(txtYourEmailAddr.Text, txtYourPassword.Text);
        c.EnableSsl = true;
        c.Send(msg);
    }
```

Hope it helps.